# Calculate the nth term of the sequence 1,3,8,22,60,164,448,1224...?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, sequence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I want to generate the nth term of the sequence 1,3,8,22,60 ,164 in Order(1) or order of (nlogn)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301992/i-want-to-generate-the-nth-term-of-the-sequence-1-3-8-22-60-164-in-order1-or)

What I do now is:

```
t1 = 1, t2 = 0,MOD = 1000000007;

for i = 1:n 

    t1_new = (2*(t1+t2)) % MOD;
    t2_new = t1;
    a[i] = (t1_new + t2_new) % MOD;   // where a[i] is the ith term mod p
    t1 = t1_new;
    t2 = t2_new;

return a[n]; // the required ans
```

But it is an O(n) solution.

Please give me only hints(no solution please) so that I can reduce the complexity of the solution.

Comment: Here's a hint: don't store the old results in an array so that `a` can become a register variable.

Comment: What is the recurrent relation between t_n and t_(n-1) ?   t_n = 2 * (t_(n-1) + t_(n-2))  ?  Try to solve this recurrence equation using the characteristic equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the folowing fact. If you consider the matrix

```
    (0 1)
A = (2 2)
```

You can use the fact that a<sub>n</sub> = A<sup>n-2</sup> * (1, 3)[1] (here (1,3) is a vector)  and [1] means second coordinate of the vector. Here you can use binary exponentiation for the matrix. Consider the cases for n<=2 separately.

Comment: Thanks! Using this I hope to get a complexity of O(log n).

Comment: Could you please explain how you came to this solution. Is this any standard sequence?

Comment: @TheRock: You can use this for any sequence that is a linear combination of previous terms. Calculate (t_{n-1}, t_n) to try and see how this works.

Comment: @TheRock: Check out the problem "Tiling Mall" in [http://olympiad.cs.uct.ac.za/old/may_2009/may_2009.pdf](http://olympiad.cs.uct.ac.za/old/may_2009/may_2009.pdf) along with the write up for the solution in [http://olympiad.cs.uct.ac.za/old/may_2009/may_2009_solutions.pdf](http://olympiad.cs.uct.ac.za/old/may_2009/may_2009_solutions.pdf). For a more complicated example of this technique.

Answer (score -1):

you don't need an array at all to achieve this.

```
int n = 5;
int result = 0;

for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
{
    int t1_new = (2*(t1+t2)) % MOD;
    int t2_new = t1;

    result = (t1_new + t2_new) % MOD;
    t1 = t1_new;
    t2 = t2_new;
}

int res = result;
```

that way, you will get the nth term, and not all of them across the way until n.

Comment: Still an O(n) time solution...